# unable to install software update in macbook

Tags: macos, ios

I am trying to install software update in macbook, but when it says downloaded completed and you need to restart your machine, I press Restart button but my machine does not restart, it just gets freezes; when I try to restart it from Apple menu it restarts but when I try to restart when software updater asks to restart it, it does not restart and blank screen appears without dock and topbar; just wallpaper appears.

I am new to Mac OS. So please help me to solve this problem and install updates successfully.

Thanks.

[ SYSTEM SPECS

Model Name: MacBook Model Identifier: MacBook4,1 Processor Name: Intel Core 2 Duo Processor Speed: 2.4 GHz Number Of Processors: 1 Total Number Of Cores: 2 L2 Cache: 3 MB Memory: 2 GB Bus Speed: 800 MHz Boot ROM Version: MB41.00C1.B00 SMC Version (system): 1.31f1 Serial Number (system): W883401J0P2 Hardware UUID: 7206FFBC-00AD-5CA2-A5B7-0466AC96016B Sudden Motion Sensor: State: Enabled

]

[ ABOUT SOFTWARE

System Version:   Mac OS X Server 10.6 (10A433)
  Server Configuration: Advanced
  Kernel Version:   Darwin 10.0.0
  Boot Volume:  master
  Boot Mode:    Normal
  Secure Virtual Memory:    Enabled
  64-bit Kernel and Extensions: No
]

Comment: We need more specific information about the specific update you're attempting to install in order to help you. 

Your system specs show your 2008 era MacBook is running 10.6 server. If that is accurate, I would first try downloading the 10.6.8 server combo updater, installing that then see if the problem continues. ...Or is that the update that is giving you the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset the PRAM before this update with CMD, OPT, P,R while the computer starting up. If the procedure done well the Mac will restart immediately.

If this doesn't work, I will try the update in Safe Boot (Boot while holding the SHIFT key, don't worry about the graphical artifacts).